# Rails I18n locale routing and RSpec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rspec, rspec2

My application was written in English and it was all good. Yesterday I starts to play with the Rails.I18n internationalization support. It is all good. When I browse `http://localhost:3000/jp/discounts` it is in Japanese, and 'http://localhost:3000/discounts' gives me the default English locale (when locale is not specified).

Here is my route.rb and as you can see, the admin namespace is not localized:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :discounts do
    resource :map, only: :show
    collection do
      get :featured_city
    end
  end
end
namespace :admin do
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :members
      get :search
    end
  end
end
```

However my RSpec starts to fail.

```
Failure/Error: it { should route_to('admin/users#edit', id: '1') }
The recognized options <{"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"users", "locale"=>"admin", "id"=>"1"}> 
  did not match <{"id"=>"1", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"edit"}>, 
difference: <{"controller"=>"admin/users", "locale"=>"admin"}>.
  <{"id"=>"1", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"edit"}> expected but was
  <{"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"users", "locale"=>"admin", "id"=>"1"}>
```

The tests related to admin all have this kind of problem. How can I resolve this? It works fine in development.

Here are other locale-related code:

#### application_controller.rb

```
  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
```

#### config/initializers/i18n.rb

```
#encoding: utf-8
I18n.default_locale = :en

LANGUAGES = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ["Japanese", 'jp']
]
```

Comment: What happens if you move your `namespace :admin` block above your `scope` block?

Comment: Thanks! It eliminates most of errors (the one left is anther issue). But I don't get the mechanics behind this as how my scope affect something outside it? Could you write the answer and is possible explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Rails attempts to match a given URL to a route, it starts at the top of the `config/routes.rb` file and stops at the first route that it considers to be a match. Since, in your original question, you had the `scope` block first, Rails thought your `/admin` URLs indicated a route with `:locale => 'admin'`.

You need Rails to match paths beginning in `/admin` to your admin namespace. By placing that first in your routes file, you cause Rails to "stop looking" once it finds that match.

This is a gross oversimplification, but I hope it's helpful.

Also check out [the Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) if you haven't already.